# __bases__ doesn't work! What's next?

Tags: python, runtime, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

The following code doesn't work in Python 3.x, but it used to work with old-style classes:

```
class Extender:
    def extension(self):
        print("Some work...")

class Base:
    pass

Base.__bases__ += (Extender,)

Base().extension()
```

**Question is simple:** *How can I add dynamically (at runtime) a super class to a class in Python 3.x?*

But I'm ready the answer will be hard! )

Comment: Your bases are no longer belong to you?  And the answer will hard?

Comment: I think this is not possible any more since all classes are new-style classes in Python 3, and the MRO would be ambiguous if `Base` had both `object` and `Extender` as base classes. Create a new class that inherits from `Base` and `Extender` instead. `Extender` might also be an ABC.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that it is possible to dynamically change `Base.__bases__`
if `Base.__base__` is not `object`. (By dynamically change, I mean in such a way that all pre-existing instances that inherit from `Base` also get dynamically changed. Otherwise see [Mykola Kharechko's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193158/bases-doesnt-work-whats-next/3193260#3193260)).

If `Base.__base__` is some dummy class `TopBase`, then assignment to `Base.__bases__` seems to work:

```
class Extender(object):
    def extension(self):
        print("Some work...")

class TopBase(object):
    pass

class Base(TopBase):
    pass

b=Base()
print(Base.__bases__)
# (<class '__main__.TopBase'>,)

Base.__bases__ += (Extender,)
print(Base.__bases__)
# (<class '__main__.TopBase'>, <class '__main__.Extender'>)
Base().extension()
# Some work...
b.extension()
# Some work...

Base.__bases__ = (Extender, TopBase) 
print(Base.__bases__)
# (<class '__main__.Extender'>, <class '__main__.TopBase'>)
Base().extension()
# Some work...
b.extension()
# Some work...
```

This was tested to work in Python 2 (for new- and old-style classes) and for Python 3. I have no idea why it works while this does not:

```
class Extender(object):
    def extension(self):
        print("Some work...")

class Base(object):
    pass

Base.__bases__ = (Extender, object)
# TypeError: __bases__ assignment: 'Extender' deallocator differs from 'object'
```

Comment: The reason for the error of "cannot create a consistent.." is because you are trying to change Base.__base__ from the value (object,) to (object, Extender), which is the wrong way around according to mro-order. (Likewise you can't say `class X(object, Extender)` which errors with similarly). However `Base.__bases__ += (Extender,) + Base.__bases__` will just throw `'E' deallocator differs from 'object'`, which is another error altogether, but still an error.

Comment: For future reference, there's a open CPython issue concerning the deallocator error: https://bugs.python.org/issue672115 (open since 2003 so don't hold your breath)

Answer (score 6):

As for me it is impossible. But you can create new class dynamically:

```
class Extender(object):
    def extension(self):
        print("Some work...")

class Base(object):
    pass

Base = type('Base', (Base, Extender, object), {})
Base().extension()
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works well! :)
But I've updated it a little :$ It's enough to add a new base class only:   `Base = type('Base', (Extender,), {})`      If you add 'Base' and 'object' classes again they will appear twice in the MRO and the interpreter will look for attributes slowly, i think.

Comment: @DenisKolodin: The two Bases in the MRO are different classes: the new one and then the old one. Look at `[id(cls) for cls in Base.__mro__]` to see they are different.

Comment: I've tested it fully and have found one serious difference (((
Type will changed for new instances only, but with __bases__ I can change attributes in exists instances that I need.
This solution isn't similar! I still search (

Comment: @DenisKolodin: maybe try to use copy.deepcopy