# Duck Typing, isinstance(), __subclasshook__() overriding, and types.MethodType() working together?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I have a class which implements a dynamic set of bound methods depending on the conditions under which it was initialized. The purpose behind doing it this way is to make the functionality of the library easily expandable through creation of a new modules containing a series of methods which will be bound to the object while also simplifying the API for the library to those not actively contributing to it.

It is not a perfect parallel, but to represent this I will use a `Dog` class which, upon initialization, acquires a series of tricks from a tricks module which in this case will be passed as a string containing the module name.

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name, module_name):
        self.name = name
        # imports module
        module = __import__("mylib.tricks.{mod}".format(mod=module_name),
                            from_list=['arbitrary argument'])
        # Dog object gets all tricks from module as bound methods
        tricks = module.__all__
        for trick in tricks:
             exec("self." + trick + "=types.MethodType(" + trick + ", self)")
```

Then, since these will be assigned as bound methods, the tricks module can contain methods like accessing the class' attributes like:

```
def speak(self):
    print 'Woof!'

def speak_name(self):
    # This is a very talented dog
    print self.name

def quack(self):
    print 'Quack!'
```

Now I'm finally to the part I'm struggling with. Using the `ABCMeta` class `__subclasshook__` method it is possible to change the behavior of the is `instance()` method so that it returns true for any class which implements a particular method. For instance we could have a `DuckABC` abstract base class meant to essentially function as an interface which also returns true for any class implementing a `quack()` method.

```
class DuckABC:
    __metaclass__=ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def quack(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, instance):
        if cls is DuckABC:
            if any("quack" in class_.__dict__ for class_ in instance.__mro__):
                return True
        return NotImplemented

class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
    def quack(self):
        # Not a very talented cat
        print 'meow'

>>> my_cat = Cat('Tom')
>>> isinstance(my_cat, DuckABC)
True
```

However, here is where my problem arises. Using this `DuckABC` abstract base class and the dynamic `Dog` class defined above the following would be true:

```
>>> my_dog = Dog('Berkley', 'name_of_module_containing_quack')
>>> my_dog.quack()
Quack!
>>> isinstance(my_dog, DuckABC)
False
```

I understand that it is not returning true, because the `Dog` class itself does not have any method called `quack` despite the fact that this particular instance of the `Dog` class learned how to quack.

So my question is: Is there any way within this framework to use the `isinstance()` method to check if a particular instance of my dog class knows how to quack? If not, what other options might I have to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: I'm interested in overloading `isinstance` for other bad reasons, so this is an interesting question. However, the `isinstance(my_cat, DuckABC)` returns `False` in Python3. Does anyone know what has changed from 2 to 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make much simpler:

```
class QuackMixin(object):
    def quack(self):
        ...

class Dog(object):
    ...

class QuackingDog(Dog, QuackMixin):
    pass

quacking_dog = QuackingDog(...)

isinstance(quacking_dog, Dog) -> True
isinstance(quacking_dog, QuackMixin) -> True
isinstance(quacking_dog, QuackingDog) -> True
```

So your `tricks` module would contain mixins. You can make a factory function which makes subclasses/instances of needed classes:

```
def make_special_dog_class(class_name, *classes):
    return type(class_name, tuple(classes), {})
```

Comment: That is an excellent solution, thanks! Now, lets say my objective was to have the user simply pass in an instantiated dog with a number of attributes, like name, and the parameter which leads me to the QuackMixin. Is there an elegant way to have the output of my factory be a QuackingDog instance with the same name and other attributes given that I may not know what all of these attributes are ahead of time?

Comment: @AmenRadix try something like `dog_object.__class__.__bases__ += (getattr(trick_module, mixin_class_name), )` See [this](http://2ndscale.com/rtomayko/2004/dynamic-superclassing-in-python) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193158/bases-doesnt-work-whats-next)

Answer (score 1):

Use `hasattr`:

```
if hasattr(dog, "Quack"): 
    dog.Quack()
else: 
    dog.Sit()
```