# How is __subclasses__ method implemented in CPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

The docs say that:

> Each class keeps a list of weak references to its immediate subclasses. This method returns a list of all those references still alive.

But how does each class obtain a list of weak references to its subclasses in the first place? In other words, when I create

```
class B(A):
  pass
```

how does `A` find out that `B` just subclassed it? And is this mechanism robust enough to survive edge cases (custom metaclasses, assignment to `__bases__`, etc.)?

Comment: Be careful with this, I learned the hard way that you have to be sure not to use `__subclasses__` until all class declarations have been imported, otherwise some items can be missing.

Comment: @wim While perhaps slightly tricky to ensure that all imports have already happened, it seems very reasonable that it works like this. After all, this is a runtime mechanism (by necessity, since class creation is dynamic in python). So it can only tell us about classes that are currently alive in the given python process.

Comment: That's true - the corollary is that you can't use it at import time unless you have good control over the import order.  Which is harder than it sounds, and fragile to changes when refactoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of the initialization of a new class, a weak reference to that class is added to the `tp_subclasses` member of each of its base classes. You can see this in the Python source code in [`Objects/typeobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l5004):

```c
int
PyType_Ready(PyTypeObject *type)
{
    ...
    /* Link into each base class's list of subclasses */
    bases = type->tp_bases;
    n = PyTuple_GET_SIZE(bases);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        PyObject *b = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(bases, i);
        if (PyType_Check(b) &&
            add_subclass((PyTypeObject *)b, type) < 0)
            goto error;
    }
    ...
}

static int
add_subclass(PyTypeObject *base, PyTypeObject *type)
{
    int result = -1;
    PyObject *dict, *key, *newobj;

    dict = base->tp_subclasses;
    if (dict == NULL) {
        base->tp_subclasses = dict = PyDict_New();
        if (dict == NULL)
            return -1;
    }
    assert(PyDict_CheckExact(dict));
    key = PyLong_FromVoidPtr((void *) type);
    if (key == NULL)
        return -1;
    newobj = PyWeakref_NewRef((PyObject *)type, NULL);
    if (newobj != NULL) {
        result = PyDict_SetItem(dict, key, newobj);
        Py_DECREF(newobj);
    }
    Py_DECREF(key);
    return result;
}
```

The [setter](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l624) for `__bases__` also updates the subclass lists of each of the old and new bases:

```c
static int
type_set_bases(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *new_bases, void *context)
{
    ...
    if (type->tp_bases == new_bases) {
        /* any base that was in __bases__ but now isn't, we
           need to remove |type| from its tp_subclasses.
           conversely, any class now in __bases__ that wasn't
           needs to have |type| added to its subclasses. */

        /* for now, sod that: just remove from all old_bases,
           add to all new_bases */
        remove_all_subclasses(type, old_bases);
        res = add_all_subclasses(type, new_bases);
        update_all_slots(type);
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that if a metaclass does something to customize the meaning of the subclass relationship, `__subclasses__` won't reflect that. For example, `issubclass(list, collections.abc.Iterable)` is `True`, but `list` won't show up in a search of the `__subclasses__` tree starting from `collections.abc.Iterable`.

Comment: So that means that an assignment to `cls.__bases__` will break the ability to find subclasses through `__subclasses__`?

Comment: I get `TypeError: __bases__ assignment: 'D' deallocator differs from 'object'` when attempting to assign to `__bases__`

Comment: @max: No, the setter for `__bases__` will keep the list up-to-date.

Comment: @AnthonySottile in python 3, you can only assign to `__bases__` [when the class doesn't directly subclass `object`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3206926/336527)